# Using one GLSL program for both textured and untextured rendering?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

Rather than have two separate shaders in my OpenGL code (one for when a texture is bound, one for when none is bound) I usually go for one shader program which handles both.  This is my usual fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform bool textured;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

in vec4 fColor;
in vec2 tCoord;

out vec4 final_color;

void main()
{
    vec4 texel = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    if (textured)
        texel = texture(sampler, tCoord);
    final_color = fColor * texel;
}
```

In a modern OpenGL profile, this compiled but did not output anything but black pixels (alternatively in LWJGL legacy profile, it outputted regular colors if textured == false and textured if textured == true).  I don't see any reason that this *wouldn't* work, but what is a method which would work for both textured and untextured fragments?

Comment: How is this question any different from [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467632/glsl-texture-method-in-if-statement-causes-screen-to-be-black)?

Comment: I decided that one was too specific, which was maybe why nobody was helping me.  So I deleted it and posted a new and improved one.

Comment: @ZachGoethel: I find it very likely that the error is in some other parts of the code which you are not showing. In principle, using a bool for that thing should work. And since this is completely uniform control flow, there should also be no issues with sampling the texture in a branch.

Comment: My solution is to always have a texture bound, and if I normally wouldn't I bind a 2x2 white texture.

Comment: hi there, has anybody found a solution to this? I am having a hard time googling for answers on why my fragment shader ignoring my if statements..